# Using timeout instead of $timeout in Angular 1.4

Tags: angularjs, settimeout, angularjs-digest

I'm implementing a hack in order to scroll the contents of an element using an Angular 1.4 directive. However the code to change the scroll position of the element needs to be done after x seconds of clicking the same element.

This directive does not absolutely nothing but change the scroll position of an HTML element.

Should I be using the native browser `setTimeout` or `$timeout` function. I feel that using `$timeout` is unnecessary as this will trigger the digest cycle (as mentioned this is unnecessary).

So my question really boils down to: Is this a good idea and are there similar or other scenarios where the use of the native `setTimeout` over `$timeout` function is warranted.

Comment: is this referred to angularjs or angular 2+?

Comment: Angular 1.4 (mentioned above, will update title)

Comment: Just FYI the angular team changed the name from angularjs to angular with version 2. To avoid confusion when talking about sub version 2 you should use angularjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJs already accounts for this.  `$timeout` and `$interval` both accept an optional parameter which will allow you to skip dirty checking:  `invokeApply` which is set to true by default.

`$timeout(someFunction, 1000, false)` will skip the `$digest`.  You should **always** use `$timeout` over `setTimeout`.  `$timeout` is a wrapper around `setTimeout` that is able to handle exceptions through the `$exceptionHandler`.

[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout/](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Comment: Aah, yes thats right, exception handling, I remember that. Thanks